# Spring Boot getting 404 errors on controller api

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm going through a tutorial on Sprint Boot and created an practice application. In my Controller class, I put the mappings in and when I run the application, I keep getting 404 errors on all my api's. I followed the tutorial step by step but I don't want to go forward yet without testing if the api's are working. I tried to change the port incase that was causing the issue but I'm thinking something is maybe blocking, that's why I'm getting the 404 err.

Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/book")
public class BookController {
    
    private final BookService bookService;
    
    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> books = bookService.findAllBooks();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(books, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> getBookByID(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Book book = bookService.findBookByID(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(book, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        Book newBook = bookService.addBook(book);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newBook, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> updateBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        Book updateBook = bookService.updateBook(book);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updateBook, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteBook(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        bookService.deleteBook(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class BookService {
    private final BookRepo bookRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    public BookService(BookRepo bookRepo) {
        this.bookRepo = bookRepo;
    }
    
    public Book addBook(Book book) {
        return bookRepo.save(book);
    }
    
    public List<Book> findAllBooks() {
        return bookRepo.findAll();
    }
    
    public Book updateBook(Book book) {
        return bookRepo.save(book);
    }
    
    public Book findBookByID(Long id) {
        return bookRepo.findBookById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException("Book by id " + id + " was not found"));
    }
    
    public void deleteBook(Long id) {
        bookRepo.deleteBookById(id); 
    }
}
```

Application properites

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookrental
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookRentalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookRentalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Output from postman

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-02-21T16:33:50.027+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/book/add"
}
```

UPDATE

URL: `http://localhost:8080/api/book/add`

Used Post request and selected JSON, this is what I put in the json body

```
{
    "bookName": "The Hunger Games",
    "authorLastName": "Collins",
    "authorFirstName": "Suzanne",
    "isbn": "9780439023481",
    "genre": "young adult"
}
```

Comment: Not sure why I got a negative on this post once I posted the question. I did look at other's post, tried there solutions, but no luck

Comment: Can u show us the postman code and url?

Comment: I think spring has not scanned your @RestController class and therefore those endpoints are not available so try including them with
`@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.*")`
change `com` with your project package name

Comment: I'll try that, I thought I read that ```@SpringBootApplication``` already includes the ```@ComponentScan```, maybe I misunderstood that

Comment: I added ```@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller.*")```, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your other package hierarchies are below your main app with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, you’re covered by the implicit Component Scan.

If there are beans/components in other packages that are not sub-packages of the main package, you should manually add them as `@ComponentScan`

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.*")
@SpringBootApplication
```

For multiple paths you can make the changes as describe below

```
@ComponentScan({"com.x","com.y"})
```

Change package name accordingly.

Comment: Wow, got it. So it was because the packages I created in eclipse where not under the main package. So I reorganized everything and it works now. I didn't add the componetScan since I reorganized everything under the main package. Not sure why it didn't do that in the first place. Thanks for that information about ```@ComponentScan```